# changing component's id name at run time

Tags: android, xml, view

Is it possible to change at run time `id` name of a component?

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:background="@drawable/single_square"
    android:onClick="itemSelected"
     />
```

`onClick` method adds random background image. Later, when it is clicked for the second time I want to know what background image was added. To do that I want to change id name (ImageButton1) of this component at the first click to the image name that was set(for example, `key_image`). How do I do that?

Comment: Why do you need to change the id? If you're just trying to keep track of the image name, you could just use a String variable, or (probably preferable) the **setTag** and **getTag** methods on the button.

Comment: thanks Mike M. yours is better idea than mine. How can I accept your comment as an answer?

Comment: Also if you could elaborate more, as i have never used them before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to change the id if you just want to keep track of the image name. Simply use a separate String variable, or (possibly preferable) the **setTag** and **getTag** methods on the Button.

An object's tag is really just a place to store additional information with that object. So, in your case, if you have a Button **btn**,  and you want to associate a String like **imageName** with it:

```
btn.setTag(imageName);
```

To retrieve the String, use:

```
String lastImageName = (String) btn.getTag();
```

**Note:** A tag can be any Object. It doesn't have to be a String, which is, in fact, why we need to cast the **getTag** result with **(String)** in our example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setId(id)` method of the `ImageButton` to set an id to your `ImageButton`..

```
imagebutton.setId(someId);
```